# Cached Thread Pool performance in WEB application

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I have `Spring Boot Application`.

It sends a request to other servers(replicas) using `restTemplate` in foreach. Only one thing is different - url address.

I think I should use `ExecutorService.newCachedThreadPool()` instead foreach in this case.

**1**.I have some `@ Controllers` with the same logic. Should I use the single `ExecutorService` for application or for each `@ Controller` its own `ExecutorService`?
**2**. `ThreadPool` behavior - If the max size has been reached, there is no idle threads, and the queue becomes full, the rejection policy kicks in.
Can I check It or just to handle an exception?

Comment: What do you mean by "application has replicas"  Its multiple instance having same App deployed ?

Comment: I have simpified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a scenario like this

Multiple instances of an App on different URL

```
AppInstance1 => localhost:8881
AppInstance2 => localhost:8882
...
AppInstanceN => localhost:888N
```

Now you can locaBalance all these App on a common URL say

```
http://localhost/
```

You can use Any load balancer like [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/)

What Load balancer does it will redirect your requests to different server based on Algorithm configured

eg. Round Robin

So when User hits `http://localhost/user/1`

`AppInstance1` or `AppInstance2`..  can serve this request